# What does "we're still here" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> People like to say Segway was a flop, but we`re still here.

What does "*we're still here*" mean in this context? Does it mean "*we are successful now*" or "*we still have a strong will to make it*"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither really.  It just means, "We are still in business."

You can use this expression in a variety of contexts where (for some reason) it was expected you would fail, but you have nevertheless persisted.

> Some people thought the Senator's personal scandals would have been the end of his political career -- but nevertheless **he's still here**, still making speeches and getting votes.